# Sony E-Mount Lens on C or CS mount Arducam (HQ) - Can I find or make an adapter?

Tags: lens-mount, lens-adapter, e-mount

I purchased the Arducam HQ, 16MP camera, bundled with a 3MP 6-50mm C mount lens (including the CS adapter)

From close I am very happy with the quality, 50cm away looks exactly as I expected. But when I try to capture something 10+ m away, the quality drops like crazy. I understand, it's not an expensive lens, so that's probably 'normal'. However, I do have old Minolta (MD, from the good old times) as well as some Sony E (NEX) mount Lenses for the Sony Alpha 7. Problem is: I can't find adapters for the NEX mount and the MD is €40+ and I have no way of trying it out. Also the NEX lenses are much newer/nicer.

So does anybody have any ideas/resources? Or experience on how well the big lens adapters work with C/CS mount?

I'd be happy with a printable model of the NEX bayonet, probably a model of the protective cap at the bottom would do already. I'm pretty good with 3D modelling, so even half a solution might help. But I didn't find much.

Comment: just a quick comment - "NEX" really isn't used as a Sony term anymore. You might have better luck omitting this term from your searches. Sony just calls it the "E mount" now. "NEX" hasn't been used for many years.

Comment: I can't figure out quite what's supposed to map to what, but probably https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y would be a good starting point.

Comment: @osullic I did try Nex and e

Comment: @Tetsujin , thanks, that looks like a very good resource, it's a lot, so I'll have to take my time. The problem is, that there are no good lenses for C-Mount, since it's CCTV and ppl don't pay good money for these kinds of purposes. I have made some good experiences with adapters, my old Minolta Lenses produce more than acceptable pictures on my Sony with an adapter.